# integer value gets wrong in C#

Tags: c#

The code is as follows. 
When I enter the value of t=2 in console,it gets printed as 50 and similarly it prints 51,52 for 3,4 and so forth.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int h = 0;
            int t = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello India!!");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the no. of test cases");

            t= Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            Console.WriteLine(t);

            for (int n = 1; n < t;n++ )
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Enter the String");
                 String str = Console.ReadLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                {
                if ((str[i] == 'A') || (str[i] == 'D') || (str[i] == 'O') || (str[i] == 'P') || (str[i] == 'Q') || (str[i] == 'R'))
                    h = h + 1;
                else if (str[i] == 'B')
                    h = h + 2;
                else
                    continue;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(h);
         } 

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly gets wrong? What is the question?

Comment: entering the value of t = 2 will print value of t=50 in Console.Writeline(t) and therefore the loop runs for 50 times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Console.ReadLine()`, not `Console.Read()`.  This will return a `string` which will convert to the number `2` properly.

```
t = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Answer (score 2):

ASCII code of `'2'` is 50, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you look closely on this table, you'll see that the symbol for `'2'` actually has the value `50`

`Console.Read()` returns an integer, more specifically it returns an integer representing the first character you put in, so say I put in `a`, `Console.Read()` will spit out `97`, if I input `A` it'll give me `65` and if I write `AB` it'll ALSO give me `65` because it reads the first char in the stream, and returns its integer value

Instead what you should do, is use `Console.ReadLine()` it takes any input, and returns it as a string, which you can then parse to an integer, so if I give it `2` it'll return `"2"` which you can then run through `Convert.ToInt32()` and get an integer out of.